# Не восстанавливается фрагмент

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Создаю приложение с фрагментами. В начале работы, загружаю фрагмент, а затем внутрь этого фрагмента подгружаю другие фрагменты по мере необходимости. Сначала всё работает. Но если выйти из приложения и через некоторое время в него зайти, всё ломается. Как я понимаю некоторые объекты выгружаются и система попытается их восстановить при последующем запуске приложения. В ЛогКэте вижу сообщение что конструктор фрагмента должен быть без параметров. Но я его создал уже!

Как быть? Может я что-то не знаю про фрагменты??? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор фрагмента должен быть без параметров. Параметры туда передаются через Bundle аргументы, если нужно.

В том месте, где создается фрагмент:

```
String myString = "test";
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("MyString", myString);

Fragment myFragment = new Fragment();
myFragment .setArguments(args);
```

При создании фрагмента проверяем, был ли он выгружен из памяти ранее, и если был, получаем сохраненные данные.

```
/**
 * Обработчик создания фрагмента
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Если фрагмент был разрушен андроидом и восстановлен заново
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         myString = savedInstanceState.getString("STRING"); // строка член класса
    }
    else {
        // Так передаются данные при создании фрагмента
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        myString = args.getString("MyString");
    }
}
```

Для сохранения состояния фрагмента используется метод

```
/**
 * Обработчик действий перед выгрузкой из памяти
 */
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("STRING", myString);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

в котором сохраняется все, что требуется сохранить.

Comment: У фрагмента могут быть конструкторы с параметрами, но тогда также необходимо явно создать и дефолтный конструктор (без параметров). В случае изменения конфигурации будет вызываться именно он

Comment: Ага, могут быть, только при таком механизме работы от них мало толка; я в итоге отказался от них.